# Inserting tuple into postegresql with python - Select statment

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Hello I am trying to insert to a pgadmin table using python, I used execute and it worked, but for my second aprt i need to use a fucntion, I got everything working except the inserts with select, it tells my syntax error, or forgot comma, literally everything. Im new, so help would be apprecitated .

```
def insrtDirector(q,w,e,r,t,y,u):
        sql1 = (q,w,e,r,t,y,u)
        insrt = """INSERT INTO "Director" VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
        cur.execute(insrt,sql1)
    insrtDirector(uuid.uuid4(), (SELECT "UName" from University WHERE "UName" = 'University College London') , (SELECT "DName" from Department WHERE "DName" ='English') , 'Christopher (3)', 'Nolan (3)', 1970, 'Westminster, London, United Kingdom' )
```

Error

```
 insrtDirector(uuid.uuid4(), (SELECT "UName" from University WHERE "UName" = 'University College London') , (SELECT "DName" from Department WHERE "DName" ='English') , 'Christopher (3)', 'Nolan (3)', 1970, 'Westminster, London, United Kingdom' )
                                        ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly use subqueries (google it!). Try something like this, it might work (and please fix your variable names, qwertyu is not good, should be descriptive like unique_id, uname, dname, first_name, etc.)

```
def insrtDirector(q,w,e,r,t,y,u):
    # Assume w and e are always subqueries with one result
    # Also assume no outside source can supply w and e (must be sanitized to not be subject to sql injection)
    insrt = "INSERT INTO Director VALUES (%s,{uname_subquery},{dname_subquery},%s,%s,%s,%s)".format(
        uname_subquery=w,
        dmane_subquery=e,
    )
    # This print command is just temporary so you can see what it looks like
    print("insert command:", insrt)
    sql1 = (q,r,t,y,u)
    cur.execute(insrt, sql1)

insrtDirector(
    uuid.uuid4(),
    "(SELECT UName from University WHERE UName = 'University College London')",
    "(SELECT DName from Department WHERE DName = 'English')",
    'Christopher (3)',
    'Nolan (3)',
    1970,
    'Westminster, London, United Kingdom',
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will rename the variables, I was just rushing and did not want to have proper names for a bunch of different table inserts. I did a little bit of editing because of psycopg2 insert format, but it worked!